# Emit message to certain socket id in socket 2.0

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I'm using socket 2.0 for a chat, and I would like to send messages from server side to a certain socket id I have stored in array. How can I do that, I don't see it clearly in socket.io docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From : https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/

```
// sending to individual socketid (private message)
  socket.to(<socketid>).emit('hey', 'I just met you');
```

Comment: The OP might want `io.to(<socketid>).emit()` if they don't happen to be in a socket.io event already and thus don't have a `socket` object handy.

Comment: Correct, the `to` method should be available both to a socket instance and the framework instance.